# Grouping multiple icons together?

Tags: css

I used [this font](http://forecastfont.iconvau.lt/), I try to combine the sun and the cloud, so they move always together even if I resize the window:

```
.sun:before{content:'\f113'; font-size:7em;color: #fbac13; font-family: iconvault;font-style:normal;-webkit-animation: rotation 5s linear infinite}

.cloud:after{content:'\f106'; font-size:7em; ; font-family: iconvault;font-style: normal;color: rgb(146, 157, 173);-webkit-animation: move 2s linear alternate infinite;text-shadow: 6px 5px 10px white,-5px -5px 10px white,-5px -5px 20px white,-5px -5px  20px white;}

@-webkit-keyframes rotation {from {transform: rotate(0deg);}to {transform: rotate(90deg);}}
@-webkit-keyframes move {from {transform: translate(-20px) ;}to {transform: translate(0px) }}
```

I dident got the idea behind: `absolute`, `relative`, `fixed`, `static`, in the website, he used `absolute`.

I am sorry for this beginner question.

NB: I dident used `before` with `after` because there will be time where I will use more than 2 icons (sun, cloud, snow, thunder)

Comment: I don't quite understand the question, but I created a fiddle so others may be better able to help you:  http://jsfiddle.net/gwaucp49/

Comment: what I try to achieve, is that the sun and cloud gets unseparated as they were one icon, so even resizing the window will not split them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/gwaucp49/1/)** what you mean?

I'm not sure if this is the best way to accomplish this, but it works:

html:

```
<div class="icon-group">
    <div class="icon sun"></div>
    <div class="icon cloud"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.icon {
    display: inline-block;
}

.icon-group {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

---

### Edit

You can try something like this for stacking your icons: **[Stacked example](http://jsfiddle.net/gwaucp49/2/)**

html:

```
<div class="icon-stack">
    <div class="sun"></div>
    <div class="cloud"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.cloud {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 20px;
}

.icon-stack {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

Comment: but how about stacking them? so they appear like in reality, I made it like this, but not responsive and can lose position if resized: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/2527234/6584027/9fd62a4e-c768-11e4-820f-f83f2a6084ef.jpg

Comment: @Abdelouahab Ok, stacked would be different. Let me take a look.

Comment: ah! so this is combining `relative` and `absolute` ! it works, thank you!